# Firefox keeps freezing after upgrade to v35 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: firefox, freeze

After upgrading to Firefox 35 on Ubuntu 14.10, I keep experiencing browser freezing every time when I open a new tab, especially when I type in the address bar. The memory usage surges dramatically after freezing. Does anyone encountering the same problem? and How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There's not much information we can go on.  Can you at least post a `free --human` and a `df --human`? (Have you rebooted since the new Firefox was updated?)

Comment: this problem affect also my ubuntu 12.04 machine, this problem started just after updating to ff 35

Comment: I've installed some other updates, and the ff lag is gone... but... in the latest updates there was nothing related to firefox... bit confused, but happy.